# Honeysuckle Flower

Tags: blessing, food, agriculture, smell

Are they primarily for fragrant smell or for kids to taste the nectar?

Do any of the Brochos Books discuss the honeysuckle for blessings for fragrance or for eating?

Answer (score 1):

Both fragrance and eating/drinking can be described as ["an enjoyment that is imbibed into the body, such as a food or smell"](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Brachot_on_a_Nice_Smell#cite_note-1).

According to [Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Brachot_on_a_Nice_Smell#:%7E:text=the%20following%20categories%3A-,Boreh%20Atzei%20Besamim,-For%20tree%20products), honeysuckle flower requires the  Atzei Besamim bracha.

Rabbi Yirmiyohu Kaganoff [explains](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/17083):

> Borei atzei besamim, "The Creator of fragrant wood (or trees)." One recites this bracha before smelling fragrant woody plants and trees or their leaves, flowers, wood, or oils. As we will see, it is disputed whether the word atzei is translated as  wood  or as trees . According to all opinions, someone who wants to smell cedar, pine, or lavender should first recite this bracha.

However......

Rabbi Dov Lev over at Aish.com, says that the "Borei Isvei Vi'samim" bracha is recited. He cites the [Shulchan Aruch in Orach Chaim 216:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.216.2?lang=bi).

> If the fragrance comes from a grass or herbaceous plant, the blessing "Borei Isvei Vi'samim" is recited.
>
> Examples in this category are mint, hyacinth and honeysuckle

In the latter case, you say "Who creates fragrant herbage".